# How to match word followed by optional list of words

Tags: regex

Want to match the string `field_` followed by any word (including underscore) for instance `field_name`, but also I'm trying to match that value followed by `.value` or `.text`

So want:

```
   field_foo
   field_bar.value
   field_baz.text
```

In 
       Hi this is field_name
       And field_bar.value are good for you

Don't want

```
  Hi this is
  And are good for you
```

This works:

```
/field\w+|field\w+\.value|field\w+\.text/
```

I wonder if there's a way to simplify the second part.

Something like this (which doesn't work)

```
/field\w+[\.value|\.text]/
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you want to match vs what you don't want to match? I'm guessing it's `field_` followed by any string of letters, followed by a possible `.` and more letters?

Comment: @بارپابابا `\w` does include `_`.

Comment: That's not very specific. Given your examples, `field.*` is sufficient.

Comment: Why not only [`field_\S*`](https://regex101.com/r/PI5S8j/2)?

Comment: @revo it would include a comma for instance: `hi field_name, how` -> `field_name,`

Comment: @OscarRyz That wasn't one of your examples.

Comment: @CAustin My apologies for the ambiguity. The answer is what Roman posted, perhaps seeing the answer may shed some light on what my question was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the possible ways:

```
field\w+(?:\.(value|text))?
```

https://regex101.com/r/E1yHVY/16

Answer (score 1):

May be this:

`field\w+?(.$|\.value|\.text)`

https://regex101.com/r/py6Cg1/2